# A simple reason that $\text{Tor}(\mathbb{C}^{*}) \neq S^1.$

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, complex-numbers, torsion-groups

Let $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ denote the group of nonzero complex numbers under multiplication, and $S^{1} \subset \mathbb{C}^{*}$ the subgroup of complex numbers of length one. Torsion elements of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ are called roots of unity.

Show that $\text{Tor}(\mathbb{C}^{*}) \subset S^1.$ Now give a simple reason that $\text{Tor}(\mathbb{C}^{*}) \neq S^1.$

**My question is:**

1- I know from here [Torsion subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^\times$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892061/torsion-subgroup-of-mathbbc-times) that the torsion elements are the roots of unity, but I do not know how to prove that $\text{Tor}(\mathbb{C}^{*}) \subset S^1.$ could anyone help me in writing a rigorous proof for that, please?

2- What is a simple reason that $\text{Tor}(\mathbb{C}^{*}) \neq S^1$?

**EDIT:**
My definition of $S^{1}$ is $\{ z \in \mathbb{C^{*}\ :\ |z|=1 }\}$

Comment: 2. There are irrational numbers.

Comment: @AnginaSeng do you mean in $Tor(\mathbb{C}^*)$ or in $S^1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a point $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $r>0$ and $\theta\in \Bbb R$ is torsion element if and only if $z^n=1$ for some $n\geq 1$. In particular, $z$ is torsion element implies $|z|^n=|z^n|=1$, so that $r=|z|=1$. Therefore, $z=re^{i\theta}$ is torsion if and only if $z=e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in \Bbb R$ with $z^n=e^{in\theta}=1$. Now, we know that $e^{i\theta}=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)=1\iff\cos(n\theta)=1$ and $\sin(n\theta)=0\iff \theta=\frac{2m\pi}{n}$ for some $m\in \Bbb Z$.

> Combining all these a non-zero element $z$ is torsion if and only if
> $z=e^{i\frac{2m\pi}{n}}$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$ with $m\in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113031/discussion-on-answer-by-sumanta-a-simple-reason-that-texttor-mathbbc).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an algebraically concise way to answer your questions:

1. In general, if $f \colon G \to G'$ is a morphism of *abelian* groups it must map the source torsion subgroup to the target torsion subgroup, in other words $f[\mathrm{T}(G)] \leqslant \mathrm{T}(G')$. In your particular case, the absolute value map $z \mapsto |z|$ implements a morphism between the multiplicative groups $\left(\mathbb{C}^{\times}, \cdot\right)$ and $\left(\mathbb{R}^{\times}_{+}, \cdot\right)$, which means that it must map $\mathrm{T}\left(\mathbb{C}^{\times}\right)$ into the torsion subgroup of $(0, \infty)$. However, this latter group is *totally ordered* (by the standard order) and thus has trivial torsion. This means that $\mathrm{T}\left(\mathbb{C}^{\times}\right) \subseteq |\bullet|^{-1}[\{1\}]=\mathbb{U}$ (my notation for the circle group) and therefore that $\mathrm{T}\left(\mathbb{C}^{\times}\right)=\mathrm{T}\left(\mathbb{U}\right)$.
2. As an abelian group (even as a topological group), the unit circle $\mathbb{U}$ is isomorphic to the quotient $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ of the additive group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ (this is intimately related to the complex exponential). It is very easy to show that $\mathrm{T}\left(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\right)=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, in other words the torsion subgroup of this latter quotient group is a proper subgroup. This entails the fact that the inclusion $\mathrm{T}(\mathbb{U}) \subset \mathbb{U}$ is proper (strict), otherwise the circle group $\mathbb{U}$ would itself be torsion (and we have seen it can't be, since it is isomorphic to a group strictly containing its torsion subgroup).

Comment: But the circle group in my question is defined as a subgroup of complex numbers so it is not totally ordered as $(\mathbb{R}^{\times}_{+},.)$ .... your point of view is not clear for me in $1.$

Comment: @Smart20 The circle group is of course defined as a subgroup of the multiplicative group of *nonzero* complexes (that is the only possible definition, all others being characterisations or isomorphic descriptions) and no one stated anything about it being totally ordered, it cannot be and doesn't have to be for the purposes of my argument. My point was that *morphism* necessarily takes torsion subgroups to torsion subgroups, so this applies in particular to the morphism given by the absolute value *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Smart20 *(cont.)* morphism which allows you to infer that the *absolute value* of any torsion element in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is a torsion element of $\mathbb{R}^{\times}_+$. It is at this stage that total orders come into play: since this latter multiplicative group of strictly positives is totally ordered, it necessarily has trivial torsion, which means that the absolute value of any torsion element of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ must be $1$. This is exactly the result you sought a proof of.