# Show that $z \notin Tor(\mathbb{C^*}).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, torsion-groups

I want to answer part(b) here in this question:

Let $C^{*}$ denote the group of nonzero complex numbers under multiplication, and $S^{1} \subset C^{*}$ the subgroup of complex numbers of length one. Torsion elements of $C^{*}$ are called roots of unity.

(a) Show that $Tor(C^{*}) \subset S^1.$ Now give a simple reason that $Tor(C^{*}) \neq S^1.$

(b) Define $z \in S^{1} $ by $z = \frac{3}{5} + i \frac{4}{5}.$ Show that $z \notin Tor(\mathbb{C^*}).$

**My question is:**

I get this hint to answer it: "Show that the real and imaginary parts of $(3 + 4i)^n$ are congruent to 3 and 4 modulo 5, respectively."

But I do not understand how proving this hint will answer the question? could anyone help me in answering this question, please?

Note that: part $(a)$ answer can be found here [A simple reason that $Tor(C^{*}) \neq S^1.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3824292/a-simple-reason-that-torc-neq-s1)

Comment: Suppose $z^n=1$ for some some $n\in \Bbb N$. Then you have $5^n=(3+4i)^n$. Now compare the real and imaginary parts using the hint.

Comment: Do I have to convert my $z$ to the polar form?@ShiveringSoldier

Comment: For me it is clear that $3 \equiv 3 (\mod 5)$ and $4 \equiv 4 (\mod 5)$  is that what you meant to say ? @ShiveringSoldier

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier I know that the imaginary part is 0. does that help in anything? Do we want to show that the argument of the given $z$ may not satisfy $\theta=\frac{2m\pi}{n}$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$ with $m\in \Bbb Z$ and so it does not belong to $Tor(\mathbb{C}^{*}).$ If so how the 3 numbers (3,4,5) will create this $\theta$?

Comment: In this case, stay away from polar form. It will merely confuse you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any $z\in \Bbb S^1$ has modulus 1 and thus can be written as
$$
z=e^{i\theta}.
$$

Such a number is a root of unity if $\exists n$ such that $z^n=e^{i\theta n}=1$. This occurs if and only if $n\theta\in2\pi\Bbb Z$.

Can you conclude?

---

It is easy to find a real number $\theta$ such that $n\theta$ doesn't belong to $2\pi\Bbb Z$. That is, the equality
$$
n\theta=2\pi m
$$
is never true, whatever $n,m\in\Bbb Z$ you take.

For example $\theta=1$ does the job.

So for such $\theta$, one *never* gets
$$
z^n=1
$$
so, such a $z=e^{i\theta}$ doesn't belong to $\operatorname{Tor}(\Bbb C^*)$, but stay obviously in $\Bbb S^1$.

Comment: I will think and let you know if I can conclude or not.

Comment: No, I am unable to conclude.

Comment: I know that the imaginary part is 0. does that help in anything? Do we want to show that the argument of the given $z$ may not satisfy $\theta=\frac{2m\pi}{n}$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$ with $m\in \Bbb Z$ and so it does not belong to $Tor(\mathbb{C}^{*}).$

Comment: I think the purely arithmetic method suggested in the hint is much more productive and explanatory.